# change table row color in Angular 6 / HTML5 based on a date value

Tags: angular, html, validation

Is there a way to validate within HTML so that I can change the background color of this row if Item.ItemDate < current date?

```
<td class="text-danger">{{ Item.ItemDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma" }}</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NgClass condition:

```
<td class="text-danger" [className]="Item.ItemDate.toDateString() < today.toDateString() ? 'yesterday' : 'tomorrow'">{{ Item.ItemDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma" }}</td>
```

Where 'tomorrow' and 'yesterday are classes in your css.

Answer (score 3):

yes you can achieve this by using [ngClass] or [ngStyle] directive to set an elements classes or style dynamically.

using

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color':Item.ItemDate < current_date ? 'green' : 'red' }"
```

or

```
[ngClass]="{'text-danger':Item.ItemDate < current_date }"
```

more example [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/)

> please note you are comparing here a date  so both the variable should
>   be of date data type

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
<td class="text-danger" [class.red]="Item.ItemDate < current date">{{ Item.ItemDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma" }}</td>
```

In css

```
.red{
 background-color: red;
}
```